# Support of the -x option

Tags: encryption

I have two Ubuntu Linux 18.04.3 LTS systems, both have `vim` identify itself as "VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)"

One of the systems supports the `vim -x` option, the other one does not.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

On one system, `vim` is a symbolic link to `vim.basic`, on the other it is a symbolic link to `vim.tiny`.

`vim.basic` supports the `-x` option.
`vim.tiny` doesn't.

Problem solved.

Comment: This answer could be improved by indicating how to manage the symlinks. I believe it's using `update-alternatives`, but I don't recall the exact arguments and don't have a system where I can easily test this right now... If you could fill in the details, that would be awesome. Thanks!